I cannot view the profilePicture that I uploaded to mongodb
I'm new to React Native, but I'm trying to improve myself on the MERN stack. From the frontend, via expo-image-picker, I can save the photo to MongoDB via Multer as a String as profilePicture in the user schema. However, when I want to fetch user information with Axios, I cannot see the image in <Image/\> even though the user's information comes as String.
import axios from "axios";

export default function UploadImage() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");

  const getUser = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("http://192.168.1.112:3000/api/users/profile");
    console.log(res.data.profilePicture);
    setImage(res.data.profilePicture);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, []);

  const addImage = async () => {
    try {
      const { status } =
        await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        alert("Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!");
        return;
      } else {
        let _image = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
          allowsEditing: true,
          aspect: [4, 3],
          quality: 1,


        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(_image));
        if (!_image.cancelled) {
          const uri = _image.assets[0].uri;
          console.log(uri);
          uploadImage(uri);
          setImage(uri);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const uploadImage = async (uri) => {

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("profilePicture", {
      uri: uri,
      name: "profilePicture.jpg",
      type: "image/png",
    });

    try {

      let response = await axios.post(
        "http://192.168.1.112:3000/upload-profile-picture/",
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        }
      );
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <View style={imageUploaderStyles.container}>
        {image && (
          <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
        )}

        <View style={imageUploaderStyles.uploadBtnContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={addImage}
            style={imageUploaderStyles.uploadBtn}
          >
            <AntDesign name="camera" size={20} color="white" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}


First Check if the url is correct, You can try using <FastImage/> instead of regular Image tag as network Images are handled better using fast image. Here is the doc for more details : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image
If you are still facing difficulty , let me know

Thanks your answer but I get the error "requirenativecomponent fastimageview was not found in the uimanager". When I did my research, I think I got the error because I used expo. How can I solve this problem?

Oh I get It, you are using expo and react-native-fast-image does not work with expo. Here is an alternative for expo . Maybe this can help. Here is the doc , you can go through and try to implement.  https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/image/

Thank you again for your interest, but this did not solve my problem. I need to solve this problem and as you said, I tried to switch the project to bare workflow all day yesterday to install FastImage. But since I had no prior knowledge, I encountered a lot of problems. It will be great if I can solve my problem with Expo.

Hey ,its needs a bit of debugging to see where the issue lies exaclty, Maybe it is a url issue. Do one thing, Check if any image url (take any url from unsplash or gettyImages) to seeif it is working correctly in  tag. If yes, then its mostly probably an issue from the APi in the image url

When I give the image link to ProfilePicture in userSchema(backend) by default, the image is displayed.
